# Audio scrub app needed

Tags: app

Hi all

A few years back, I was able to scrub the audio (with my finger) in a youtube vid, when playing back stuff on my android phone.
Unfortunately I updated the phone, and it was suddenly not able to do this anymore.
I have tried to find a way to do this since then, but with no luck.

The cool thing was, that I was able to scrub fast or slow, and the audio would play back accordingly.

Any of you can help me figuring out what to do, or know of an app doing this?

Best wishes, Mikkel

Comment:   You mean "an app" as in some iOS (or in your case Android) "app"?

Comment:   Btw, "scrub" is a standard feature in many DAWs, notably Pro Tools. 

Comment: Thanks for helping out. Yes an app. Preferably for iPad if possible. The scrubbing in Protools is not very useful when scrubbing  2mins forward or backwards in seconds. 

Comment: That would depende on the zoom you have. If you have the edit window reeeeally zoomed in you can do incredibly slow scrubs. It's really cool to do on voices, did some spaceship layers that way

Comment: Wow. Didnt know that was possible. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

If you use linux then sweep is all about scrubbing... http://www.metadecks.org/software/sweep/

Comment: Dont use Linux Doug. Seems very interesting though!

Answer (score 0):

Hi Mikkel,

I built a multipurpose scrubber in max/MSP a while back. You can find it [here](http://sounddesignwithmax.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/tapehead-sample-playback-for-sound.html) if you would like a go (use the download link to *tapehead 1.0* for the program itself). You will need the max runtime for it to function which you can find [here](http://cycling74.com/downloads/).

I'd be interested to know if it does what you need it to, so any feedback is welcome!